# Moving avg using OVER RANGE BETWEEN days

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range, between

I want to find the average of item price bought within the last 365 days. Items are not guaranteed to be bought every day, so I can't fix the number of rows to look back at. So I am trying to use RANGE instead of ROWS, specifying that I look back 365 days from current row's date.

Sample data:

- Group by Store and Item
- I want to find the avg of prices bought within the last 12 months

| Store | Item | Date bought | Price | Avg price across last 365 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | Item 1 | 1/2/2022 | 1.00 | 1.00 |
| Store 1 | Item 1 | 6/1/2022 | 1.75 | 1.375 |
| Store 1 | Item 1 | 11/2/2022 | 2.10 | 1.617 |
| Store 1 | Item 1 | 1/5/2023 | 3.00 | 2.283 |
| Store 2 | Item 1 | 3/2/2022 | 1.55 | 1.55 |
| Store 2 | Item 1 | 5/5/2022 | 2.80 | 2.175 |

I have tried:

```
SELECT  
    store, item, date, price,
    SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY store, item
                     ORDER BY date ASC
                     RANGE BETWEEN 365 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_price
FROM table
```

Error I get is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 102
> Incorrect syntax near 'DAY'

I have tried these variations to address the error but can't get past it:

1. `RANGE BETWEEN '365' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`
2. `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 365 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`
3. `RANGE BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

#3 produces the error

> Msg 4194, Level 16, State 1, Line 98
> RANGE is only supported with UNBOUNDED and CURRENT ROW window frame delimiters.

Is this a syntax error? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really support `range`. Try a subquery or outer apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good old self-join should work (I converted your dates into ISO format):

```sql
with cte as (
    select *
    
    from (
        VALUES  (N'Store 1', N'Item 1', N'2022-01-02', 1.00, 1.00)
        ,   (N'Store 1', N'Item 1', N'2022-06-01', 1.75, 1.375)
        ,   (N'Store 1', N'Item 1', N'2022-11-01', 2.10, 1.617)
        ,   (N'Store 1', N'Item 1', N'2023-01-05', 3.00, 2.283)
        ,   (N'Store 2', N'Item 1', N'2022-03-02', 1.55, 1.55)
        ,   (N'Store 2', N'Item 1', N'2022-05-05', 2.80, 2.175)
    ) t (Store,Item,[Date bought],Price,[Avg price across last 365 days])
    )
select  AVG(c2.price), c.Store, c.Item, c.[Date bought]
from CTE c
LEFT JOIN CTE c2
    On  c2.Store = c.Store
    AND c2.Item = c.Item
    AND c2.[Date bought]  between DATEADD(YEAR, -1,CAST(c.[Date bought] AS DATETIME)) AND c.[Date bought]
GROUP BY c.Store, c.Item, c.[Date bought]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I initially tried a similar JOIN but my date criteria was using c2.[Date bought] > c.[Date bought] - 365
and that wasn't working for me so I was stuck using JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  
    store, 
    item, 
    date, 
    price,
    AVG(price) AS avg_price
FROM table
WHERE
    date > (select dateadd(year, -1, getdate()));
GROUP BY
    store,
    item,
    date,
    price
```

the `WHERE` query will reduce your data to all the input in the last year. SQL already comes with an averageing functions called `AVG`. Remove the `GROUP BY` if you don't want all of your data to be in groups.